# Milestone Actions and Case Validation Rules

Tags: validation-rule, casemilestone

I have some case milestone warning actions (field updates on Case).  Under some circumstances, I want these to not run. I am unable to put any conditions on such actions, and so I have tried to add a validation rule on the case object to prevent the action from doing the field update.  But the validation rule seems to be ignored.  This is not documented anywhere.  Has anyone else seen or read about this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe with the OOTB Salesforce Entitlement Processes you can set criteria for when actions run.

Your idea of setting a validation rule is an interesting workaround. Validation rules IMO should be triggered on the record update. It could be worth checking the debug logs to understand what is / is not hapening.

Since you can set criteria for a milestone to be triggered, A potential workaround could be to create a separate 'Milestone' for the process for the cases that should trigger that action and another one for the cases that should not trigger that action (I believe these can both use the same defined milestone). You can then adjust the criteria for the milestone to be triggered accordingly and define different actions on the relevant milestones as appropriate.

Another idea is to use the same milestone to update a new custom field on Case (i.e, Trigger_Milestone_Actions__c) and then have some other automation like a flow or trigger selectively fire other actions when 'Trigger_Milestone_actions__c' is set to true.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Entitlements/milestones have lots of gotchas which, unfortunately, affect almost every part of your well thought out answer.  You cannot run debug logs when a milestone action happens, which is the same behavior as time-based workflows.  So I can't actually figure out what is happening.  In addition, when you do a field update as part of a milestone action, you cannot run any other workflow i.e workflows rules, flow, process builder.  Your other suggestions are good, but won't work with my specific use case.

Comment: got it. I have hit some similar issues when trying to implement the entitlement processes as per business requirements. The feature Salesforce provides is ok but I also find that it misses the mark in many areas. GL, if you find a solution please post the answer here!